# Extract date (YYYYMMDD) from filename in bash script

Tags: bash

I am trying to extract a date from a filename. This is what I do:

```
find ${DPPATH}/${DBNAME}*.dmp.gz ${MTIMECMD} -type f -exec
```

(perform an action. this works as expected.)

What I would like to do, is extract the date (it will be in YYYYMMDD format) from the filename that is being found via the find command, and use that date to pass to the find command, where the action is being performed.

I've tried this to try and grab the date above the find command in the script, hoping to extract:

```
MOVEDATE=echo ${DPPATH}/${DBNAME}*.dmp.gz ${MTIMECMD} -type f |grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]{8}';
```

Edit, tried this suggestion:

```
${MOVEDATE}=echo ${DPPATH}/${DBNAME}*.dmp.gz ${MTIMECMD} -type f |grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]{8}'\;
```

Results was:

```
=echo: not found
```

Then, pass $MOVEDATE to the find command with no luck.

I am using the 'debug' option in the script (`-x`), and the result is:

```
<filename>  cannot execute [Permission denied]
```

The filename will named like this:

```
blah_blah_blah_exp_01_20180221_0100.dmp.gz:
```

The MTIMECMD from above is just a variable that looks for a file older than x amount of hours.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you want to store the result of a command in a variable, you need to say `var=$(command)`. If you say `var=echo ...` what you are trying to do is to execute the command "var=echo" with the rest of the string as parameters.

Comment: please [edit] your question so we see code properly

Comment: Thanks, Ive made the change to this: `${MOVEDATE}=echo ${DPPATH}/${DBNAME}*.dmp.gz ${MTIMECMD} -type f |grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]{8}'\; ` The result is: 
`line 331: =echo: not found`

Comment: No, what I meant was saying `movedate=$(echo ...)`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Ive changed to this:

`MOVEDATE = $(echo ${DPPATH}/${DBNAME}*.dmp.gz ${MTIMECMD} -type f |grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]{8}')`

and I see:

`+ MOVEDATE '=' 20180311 20180312 20180312 20180312 20180312 20180312
/lfs/dba/scripts/backup/export_backup_s3_TEST.ksh[331]: MOVEDATE: not found [No such file or directory]`

I think I may be using it wrong in the next line:

`COMMAND ${MOVEDATE}`

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is something like that :

```
MOVEDATE=$(ls -1 ${DPPATH}/${DBNAME}*.dmp.gz ${MTIMECMD} |grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]{8}')
```

It tells bash to assign to the variable `MOVEDATE` the result of the command in parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be working. However, I am not sure how to use the value of MOVEDATE later on in the script.

Comment: use `${MOVEDATE}` like in `echo ${MOVEDATE}`